# Django on Docker - relation "django_session" does not exist at character 109

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run Django project based on [coockiecutter](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html) using Docker but I get these errors:

full output: https://dpaste.de/eKF5

```
sudo docker-compose up
crm_postgres_1 is up-to-date
Starting crm_django_1
Starting crm_nginx_1
Attaching to crm_postgres_1, crm_django_1, crm_nginx_1
django_1    | Postgres is up - continuing...
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-02-15 10:39:52 UTC
postgres_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
postgres_1  | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
postgres_1  | LOG:  shutting down
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is shut down
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-02-15 10:41:58 UTC
postgres_1  | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
postgres_1  | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgres_1  | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
postgres_1  | ERROR:  relation "django_session" does not exist at character 109
postgres_1  | STATEMENT:  SELECT "django_session"."session_key", "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '2017-02-15T11:04:25.807267+00:00'::timestamptz AND
```

What should I check? I can't debug this by myself.

Answer (score 7):

You need to run the migrations to create the database tables.

Normally, you use the migrate command to do this.

```
python manage.py migrate
```

In your case, you need to run migrate inside the container. The [Cookiecutter-Django docs](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html#run-your-app-with-docker-compose) give instructions how to do this:

```
docker-compose run django python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: I did it earlier(before I asked the question)

Comment: What happened when you ran it? Since the tables don't exist, it looks like it didn't work, but you haven't provided any info to help debug.

Comment: I get standard information that all migrations was performed, for example: Applying xxx.0003_auto... OK etc. If I run this now I have: https://dpaste.de/6XZz

Comment: I started again from scratch and now I have: https://dpaste.de/iLyb - On 127.0.0.1 is `Internal Server Error`. Logs are here: https://dpaste.de/GXbY

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively run the migrations just only for the sessions app.

```
docker-compose -f production.yml(local.yml) run django python manage.py 
migrate sessions
```

Answer (score 0):

If running the "migrate" command does not create the table for you then check the django_migrations" table for entries in the "app" column named "sessions"
If there are entries then delete them (delete from django_migrations where app = 'sessions';) and rerun "migrate" script.
Same applies to other apps you may be using that are missing the databases table(s) ... the migrate script will only run a script that is not listed in the django_migrations table.

Answer (score 0):

Something that works for me,

First I executed the command `docker-compose build` for create the image, then `docker-compose up`.

Once my django server is up, I opened another command line, connected to the container (`docker exec -it container_name bash`) and execute inside the `python manage.py migrate; python manage.py makemigrations`.

By the way, these are my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml files contents:

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

```
version: '3'

services: 
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: It seems running makemigrations inside docker caused problem. After exploring for a really long time, I resolved this issue only by running makemigration under the SQLite setting and then changed setting to postgresql, get the docker running and run migrate inside the docker.